# cant install fastcgi ubuntu server: Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available

Tags: apache-2.2, installation, mod-fastcgi, ubuntu-12.04

When i try to install fastcgi in ubuntu server 12.04 I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`libapache2-mod-fastcgi` can be found in [multiverse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). If I remember correctly, a default installation of Ubuntu used not to enable *multiverse* (but should nowadays).

Maybe its disabled on your system and you'll have to add it to the list of repositories (as easy as editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and appending *multiverse* after *main* or using the graphical packet manager).

Debian ships `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` as part of *non-free* by the way, so that's probably a licence issue.

Comment: The multiverse respository was not enabled. Thanks.

Comment: after you append multiverse to the file you need to run apt-get update then it all worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This package can be found in ubuntu 12.04 packages as [shown here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2%20fastcgi&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all). You may have invalid apt sources. Did you do any changes to your sources?

You can also try to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update your packages list and upgrade the packages that need to be upgraded.

Comment: agreed, must be your repository that is setup wrongfully. make sure that in sources.list, you only have 'precise' for the ubuntu deb  entries or you may run into package dependency problems in regards to version numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot run a proper update/upgrade, try issuing following

```
sudo apt-get check
```

and if there are found 'broken dependencies', run what khaled said with `-f` parameter added, like so:

```
sudo apt-get -f update
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .deb file from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libapache2-mod-fastcgi  and install with using sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
This solution is work for me.